# How can I backup apps while in Safe Mode?

Tags: backup, safe-mode

My phone is stuck on boot problem and I was recommended to wipe it all. However I still manage to get into Safe Mode.

My question: how can I backup my apps while in safe mode? No need to backup all apps, just a few important ones (among others: Kiwi Browser, Daylio [Journaling app], Swipetimes [time tracker], Sleep for Android, Expense Manager).

I already use the Android default backup but it seems like it only backup Google apps. I unfortunately do not use Helium or Titanium Backup.

My phone is not rooted. Any help?

Comment: You can only use adb in this case, and there is no guarantee you would be able to backup all the apps you want to backup. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/how-to-fully-backup-non-rooted-devices?rq=1

Comment: @Firelord I'm fine with contacts, calendars, etc. I'm more concerned with things like sleep log or browser history or currently opened tabs. AFAIK those are hidden within directories accessible only through roots. Can the solution there backup those too?

Comment: Can you try using `adb backup`?

Comment: @TipzTeam how can I know they are fully backed?

Comment: for some apps they don't backup, like the WearOS app